# Append a char to a std::vector<string> at a specific location

Tags: c++, string, vector, char

I've looked everywhere and although I've found how to insert `std::string` into `vector<char>`, I can't find a way to insert a `char` into a `std::vector<std::string>`

In a text editor project, I'm restricted to using a vector of strings, while the thing that checks when a character is input to the text editor must take in a char and returns a char.

If I know where I am going to insert a character into this vector, what can I call to make this happen?

As a side note, I tried doing `lines.push_back(&c)` where I define lines as `std::vector<std::string>`, but it says:

```
candidate function not viable: no known
      conversion from 'char' to 'const value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::basic_string<char,
      std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >') for 1st argument
    _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void push_back(const_reference __x);
```

Comment: `lines.emplace_back(1, c)`, or `lines.push_back(std::string(1, c))`

Comment: Create a string from the character, and then insert the string?

Comment: Do you want the character appended to the string at a specific location in the vector or do you want a string of length 1 inserted into the vector at the specified location?

Comment: @ChrisDrew I want the character appended to the current string vector at a specific location.

Comment: @Alex I think the confusion is because you say you want to append a *character*, but you can't append characters to a vector of strings. You can append a character to a string, or you can append a string to the vector.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah.. sorry about that. I guess I would want to, if possible, convert a character into a string, and then I would want to insert that string into my vector at a specific row in a specific column, represented by ints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to append the vector with a new element that will have only one character you can write

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

//...

v.push_back( { 1, 'A' } );
```

If you want to append a character to already existent element of the vector you can write

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

//...

v[i] += 'A';
```

or

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

//...

v[i].push_back( 'A' );
```

If you want to insert a character inside a string of some existent element of the vector you can write

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

//...

v[i].insert( position, 1, 'A' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert a char into a vector of strings.  You'll have to convert that char into a string.  You can do that with this roundabout way:

```
string s = "";
char c = 'a';
s += c;
```

or more directly:

```
string s(1,c);
```

Then just push the string into the vector:

```
lines.push_back(s);
```

If you want to insert this into a specific position, you'll have to calculate the position and then:

```
lines.insert(position, s);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert the character at a specific position in a specific vector:

```
lines[i].insert(j, 1, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope below code snippet helps,

```
  std::vector<std::string> line;
  string s(1, c); 
  lines.push_back(s);
```

For vector of std::string. Then you have convert the c char to std::string and insert into vector.